# Android 14 : media access permission when loading videos recorded in my app

Tags: android

My app has a function to record videos within the app and save them on the device.
There is also a function to load a list of videos saved on the device.

1. Open my app.
2. In Android 14, select the “Select photos and videos” item in the media access permission dialog.
3. Record videos in my app, save them on the device, and load the list of saved videos.
4. No permissions are needed to let my app list and play those recorded files.

Why do I need no permissions when loading or playing videos recorded in my app?

The code below is the code I use to load the video file.

```
fun getVideoFiles(context: Context) : List<String> {
        val videoItemHashSet = HashSet<String>()
        val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)

        val collection: Uri = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
        } else {
            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        }
        val cursor: Cursor? = context.contentResolver.query(collection, projection, null, null, null)
        try {
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.count > 0) {
                    cursor.moveToFirst()
                    do {
                        videoItemHashSet.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)))
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext())
                }
                cursor.close()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return ArrayList(videoItemHashSet)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> > No permissions are needed when loading or playing videos recorded in my app.

You should have said instead:

No permissions are needed to let my app create video files.

No permissions are needed to let my app list and play those recorded files.

This comes true indeed.